# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Error filling tableAdaptor

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I try to fill a TableAdaptor with a table in SQL lite and faced this error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

how can I resolve it?
here is the line I got error

```
orderAdapter.Fill(ds.Orders);
```

Comment: you are trying to insert `string` value to 'DateTime' field in the dataset? check for it

Comment: No type of the column causes error is System.dateTime but I know there is a problem with sql-lite date.I have read many solutions about it but none of them worked

Comment: Have you debugged to see what the actual data is that you are trying to fill it with?

Comment: yeah its System.DateTime

Comment: That is the type that your tableadapter is expecting, I am referring to the actual value in the sqlite database, have a look at that one. Do the select that you want your Fill to do and see what the actual values are, somewhere there is something that is not a valid datetime

Comment: hmm. can be caused by locale based on your environment. did you try `ds.Orders.UtcNow()`?

Comment: there is no method named UtcNow()

Comment: @BerndLinde:the actual value is like 1899-12-30 12:00:00 AM in sqllite

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur when you try to insert

> insert into user(infoDate) values('"+DateTime.Now.ToString()+"');

Solution is you must insert using SqlCommand

> SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO user (infoDate) VALUES (@value)",   connection);
>
> cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", DateTime.Now);
>
> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();